# Ruby on Rails model reference multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, model

Im really new to Rails and currently involved in a project in which I have to develop a blog for music news, my question is: Whats the best way to design a model which has multiple images?, this images must be uploaded by the users in the views _form and then being able to use them within the content section as an  resource . Ive used Paperclip to create a model Post which has a set of images, but I want to be able to add multiple without the need to declare them in my model, something like a hasmany relationship. Is it possible to do this, if not, is it possible to upload to AWS and get the url from there as each file gets uploaded?

### Here is the model I have at the moment.

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :caption, :content, :style, :subtitle, :title, :rect_image, :image_one, :image_two, :image_thr
    validates :caption,  :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 40 }
    validates :title, :presence => true,:length => { :minimum => 20 }, :uniqueness => true
    validates :content, :presence => true,:length => { :minimum => 400 }
    before_save :create_permalink
    has_attached_file :rect_image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    has_attached_file :image_one, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    has_attached_file :image_two, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    has_attached_file :image_thr, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    #Validacion de Attachments
    #validates :rect_image, :attachment_presence => true
    #validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, :attributes => :rect_image
    def to_param
        permalink
    end
    def self.search(search)
        if search
            where 'title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"
        else
            scoped
        end
    end
    private
    def create_permalink
      self.permalink = title.downcase
    end
end
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: My main idea was being able to upload images and then using them within the content of the post, I used https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor to make uploads to the server with carrierwave as @Henry suggested, at the moment the uploads are to the public folder of Rails but i will try to modify it to upload to AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_images
  ...
end

class PostImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

If you want to get image from an url, use carrierwave.

Comment: Thanks, think Ill use carrierwave since it lets me upload files to AWS easily ill just have to deal with the retrieval of the images at the time user uploads them. Thanks a lot :)